# Backbone model not correctly accepting JSON response to POST save

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, express

I've been trying to save my model to the server and want to return an ID and other attributes. However, it seems to be accepting the response as a string rather than a JSON object and is just adding the whole string. On the server I'm using the express framework and the express-json module to serve the JSON response (which I've used before and is simply a case of calling the `res.json(dataObject)` function), so it should be sent correctly. Can anyone understand what's going wrong? See the photos or please ask for more information.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: The screenshots are not enough as you have an id in that model - we need to see the code where the exception is happening

Comment: it looks like the server is posting back the image, which is a file, instead of the json object you want.

Comment: @Dominic If you look closely, you'll see that the model doesn't have an id - because it's used the entire JSON response string as a key rather than parsing it.

Comment: @Craicerjack The second image shows the server's response, which appears to be correct JSON, so it's not sending the image file back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The issue was that the response was being sent out as plain text rather than with the correct JSON header. I needed to send an "accepts" header with the request, otherwise Express wouldn't allow me to set the corrrect "content-type" header on the response, and, in turn, Backbone wouldn't properly parse it without this. So, in case anyone's interested, I added the following to the options object of my jQuery AJAX call in the Backbone model's sync method:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
}
```